# Can only http module render ejs to html and pug to html?

Tags: node.js, express, pug, render, ejs

in case http module , it have option to encode utf8 but i think there is no option in express module , is it true? there is now way to render by express?

```
const express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();

app.use('/','utf8',(request,response) =>{
    fs.readFile('./render.ejs',(err,data)=>{
       fs.send(data) 
    });
});

app.listen(2000, ()=>{
    console.log('http://127.0.0.1:2000');
})
```

this code is only to make err

Comment: It is not clear to me what You would like to do? Do You ask how to render pug, ejs files with express.js?

Comment: sure that is what i want to know

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Overview**

Pug, ejs - those are example of template engines and the answer to Your question is: Yes, express supports it. What's more You can even create Your own template engine and use it in application what can bring a lot of fun (tutorial from official documentation: [Developing template engines](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/developing-template-engines.html)).

To use for example `pug`, You have to install it:

- `npm install pug --save` or `yarn add pug`

Tell express that You gonna use that specific one:

- `app.set('view engine', 'pug')`

**Example**

Lets assume that You have installed pug, express and You have that template in Your app:

```
html
  head
    title= title
  body
    h1= message
```

So to render it with custom title and message, go like that:

```
app.get('/hello-world', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!' })
})
```

When someone will request `'/hello-world'` path with GET request, it will serve html template with:

- `<title></title>` in head element container -> `Hey`
- `<h1></h1>` in body element -> `Hello there!`.

Here is the full example: [Doc example](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)